# Technique to add csv data for varying fields

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape results from a site (has no captcha , simple roll-no authentication, and the pattern of roll-no is known to me). The problem is that they have the results in a table format and many students have different subjects. The code I wrote so far in Python is

```
for row in rows:
            col=row.findAll('td') #BeautifulSoup object
            sub=col[1].text.encode('utf-8') #Header.(Subject Names)
            subjectname.append((sub))

            marks=col[4].text.encode('utf-8')
            markall.append((marks)) 
csvwriter.writerows([subjectname,])
csvwriter.writerows([markall,])
```

I want to generate a .csv file so that I can do some data analysis on it. Now the problem is I want a table which has a specific subject column and marks of it. But the scraper won't know if it's a different subject and will append marks of whatever subject it finds in that row/column pair.

How do I approach this?

Here's a visual representation of the problem. [image]

So if I have Subject A at column 1 , I want to get marks only of subject A and not any other subject. Do I need to create a list for all marks ?

Edit : Here's the HTML table markup https://jsfiddle.net/rpmgku7m/

Comment: Could you show the HTML representation of the table, so that it would be reproducible for us? Thanks.

Comment: Sure , here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rpmgku7m/